# How to create a conditional match with index in Excel?

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match

I am trying to use the match formula in XLS with multiple conditions, embedded within an index formula, to extract values from a sub-group as illustrated below. And without using the array function where you must enter  in order to execute. I've used conditional matches before as described in https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria but in this example I'm at a loss as to how to do this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

**Here is a solution** that seems to work, after I fiddled around some more with index/match:

[image]

Comment: Why would row 4 expect a `N/A` instead of 1.3 (which would be the count of that type within that group)?

Comment: In the more complete XLS this derives from, all NA's go through further manipulations that aren't illustrated here for sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula `IF(E20>0,E20,INDEX($E$20:$E$25,MATCH(1,INDEX((ROW()<>ROW($D$20:$D$25))*(D20=$D$20:$D$25)*($C$20:$C$25>0),0,1),0)))` in the first row for this conditional index/match, then copy down to the entire length of the target array. Please see OP edit labeled with **Here is a solution** for a working example.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).